# Ideal Marker Sizes

Tags: android, osmdroid

I'm currently re-writing an application that uses OSMDroid (new design, new functionalities, etc) and I need to know which are the ideal sizes for the custom markers.

I need for xhdpi, hdpi, mdpi, ldpi. I'm asking because earlier version of the application I used some random sizes and on some devices it looked awfull.

Hope you guys can give me some idea about it since my extended search wasn't enough to find an answer to my question.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what the right size is for you but the thing that makes it tricky compared to normal Android graphics is that the map data is displayed with no scaling so how much you get depends on the device, there is no concept of density independent pixels as far as the map data is concerned.  If you have just a single graphic for the marker and display it with no scaling then it will at least always be the same relative size to the map data.  If you provide differnt density markers then the relative size compared to the map data will change.

Comment: So you're saying that I should use just a single `drawable` with no scaling and it automatically scales with the map?